# Accessing a static class variable from a file in a different package

Tags: python, class, static

I have the following file structure in my Python project:

```
Main.py
classes
  |--- __init__.py
  |--- Common.py
  |--- Logger.py
  |--- Dictionary.py
```

I'm setting a static variable of the `Common` class from within my `Main` file:

```
from classes.Common import Common

# set path to the log file for log output
Common.set_log_file_path(C:\\logging\\output.txt"))
```

which gets set in the `Common` class:

```
class Common():
    log_file_path = ''

    @staticmethod
    def set_log_file_path(log_file_path):
        Common.log_file_path = log_file_path
```

Now I instantiate a `Logger` object from within my `Main` file:

```
from classes.Logger import Logger

# initiate logger
log = Logger()
```

The `Logger` object reads the log file path from the Common object which works fine:

```
from Common import Common

class Logger():
    log_file_path = ''

    def __init__(self, log_file_path=''):
        # if not specified, take default log file path from Common class
        if log_file_path == '':
            self.log_file_path = Common.log_file_path
```

Now comes the problem: From my `Main` file I instantiate a `Dictionary` object:

```
from classes.Dictionary import Dictionary

# load dictionary
dictionary = Dictionary()
```

In the dictionary object I also want to have a logger, so I create one there:

```
from Logger import Logger

class Dictionary():
    log = Logger()

    def __init__(self):
        Dictionary.log.info('Dictionary > __init__()')
```

But this one doesn't work. Somehow when the Logger from within the Dictionary tries to load the log file path from the `Common` class, it is empty.

Why is that so? Shouldn't that be the same `Common` class and therefore holding the same static information here? Am I missing something? Do I do the imports in a wrong way?

I'm working with Python 2.6.5, and my imports are as follows:

```
Main.py imports Dictionary, Logger, Common
Dictionary.py imports Logger
Logger.py imports Common
Common has no imports
```

Comment: Did you set the path _before_ importing `Dictionary`?  Code that depends on the import order or expects some code to run before import is a nightmare to debug and maintain.  Also make sure you don't have circular imports.  Having class level fallback attributes is a nice hack but IMHO also exactly that: a hack.

Comment: I have all includes Java like at the top before any other code - therefore I think that should be fine. I added my import structure to the question - also no circular imports.

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything in a Python module is dynamically executed — including `import` and `class` statements.

When you import the `Directory` module the first time the module is executed which means the `import` statement which imports `Logger` is executed and after the `Logger` is imported the `class Directory:` is executed which instantiates a `Logger` object.  At this point your `Common.set_log_file_path()` was not yet called so that `Logger` object takes the default value which is defined when `class Common:` was executed.

The ”solution” would be importing `Common` and set the default path before executing anything that actually uses that default path attribute:

```
from classes.Common import Common
Common.log_file_path = 'C:/logging/output.txt'
from classes.Directory import Directory
from classes.Logger import Logger
```

Solution in quotes because having imports depending on other code being executed before is something that can turn into little nightmares very easily.  Therefore it is something very seldom seen in productive code.